# Recent Queries in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using a PHP web application to interact with a database and need to catch an erroneous query. It's dynamically generated SQL and I don't know 100% of the code nor did I write it so I need to see what it's doing.

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 I've found it amazingly hard to find the last n executed queries on the database. I've searched up a storm but all solutions I've seen require "sql_handle" which is a feature not availible in my database's compatibility level, and to boot all solutions I've seen don't appear to catch dynamic queries, which this web application uses.

I was using this query:

```
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM(SELECT COALESCE(OBJECT_NAME(s2.objectid),'Ad-Hoc') AS ProcName,
  execution_count,s2.objectid,
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(s2.TEXT,statement_start_offset / 2+1 ,
      ( (CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = -1
  THEN (LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),s2.TEXT)) * 2)
ELSE statement_end_offset END)- statement_start_offset) / 2+1)) AS sql_statement,
       last_execution_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s1
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2 ) x
WHERE sql_statement NOT like 'SELECT TOP 50 * FROM(SELECT %'
ORDER BY last_execution_time DESC
```

But it unacceptably requires changing sp_dbcmptlevel in SQL Server 2005 (the search requires comptlevel at 90, I need it at 80), and in a recent case doesn't even return any dynamic queries run on the database; it's only returning the actions of stored procedures.

A similar solution with the same problems of compatability and incomplete results is:

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

This one returns a very small and very odd subset of queries, including the most recent query (usually itself) and a bunch of `create procedure` statements.

Is there any feature of SSMS or system database query that will allow me to view or capture recent queries? If I have to capture and save the query strings somehow that's acceptable as this is only in a test system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Server Profiler](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/SQLServerProfiler.aspx) [was designed to do this](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9835.using-sql-server-profiler.aspx).

With it you can:

- capture queries as they are executed on the target instance
- capture other instance and database events like deadlocks, logins, and errors
- filter captured queries by text in the query, login name, database name, and so forth

Comment: Perfect, catches a bit more info than I need but I'm tinkering with the filters.

Comment: @SirTapTap - You can select the combination of events, columns, and column filters that gives you just what you need. When you've done that, be sure to save it as a template so you can reuse that configuration in future Profiler sessions.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the SPID that is running the queries, this will give you the last statement run:

```
DECLARE @sqltext VARBINARY(128)

SELECT @sqltext = sql_handle
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = 85 --replace this with your SPID

SELECT TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sqltext)
```

Comment: Helpful but is there any way to get more than one statement from this? Unfortunately the operation I'm analyzing is a large series.

Comment: Nope, as you noted above the Profiler is better for that sort of thing. We found the above query useful because we had one column that was being changed and implemented a temporary trigger to write the results of that query to a table because profiling all of the possible databases (and not knowing when or where the data could be changed) wasn't feasible.

Comment: You could configure Profiler via column filters to capture just the queries that include the column name in question, just on the databases in question.

Comment: @Nick, granted yes. 150+ databases = no bueno though :)